# Blocking an IP in Webmin

Tags: firewall, iptables

I've been checking my `/var/log/secure` log recently and have seen the same bot trying to brute force onto my Centos server running webmin.

I created a chain + rule in Networking -> Linux Firewall:

```
Drop    If source is 113.106.88.146
```

But I'm still seeing the attempted logins in the log:

```
Jun  6 10:52:18 CentOS5 sshd[9711]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jun  6 10:52:18 CentOS5 sshd[9711]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): error retrieving information about user larry
Jun  6 10:52:19 CentOS5 sshd[9711]: Failed password for invalid user larry from 113.106.88.146 port 49328 ssh2
```

Here is the contents of `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`:

```
# Generated by webmin
*filter
:banned-ips - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport ftp-data -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport ftp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport domain -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport https -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport http -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport imaps -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport imap -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport pop3s -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport pop3 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport ftp-data -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport ftp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport domain -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport smtp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
-A banned-ips -s 113.106.88.146 -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed
# Generated by webmin
*mangle
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed
# Generated by webmin
*nat
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed
```

Comment: Your chain *banned-ips* doesn't seem to be linked to the INPUT chain. Try `iptables -I INPUT -j banned-ips`

Comment: Any reason you put both "-m tcp" and "-p tcp"? One of them should be enough, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went and installed ConfigServer Firewall - the bot got banned within minutes of installing it.

http://www.configserver.com/free/csf/install.txt

@ripat You may be correct in why my rule was not being picked up - I think Webmin's UI is at a disjoint to what iptables requires.

Answer (score 0):

I would :

1.doublechechk if it's the same ip

2.allow only from your IP

3.change webmin port to a random one

Comment: 1: Yes - you can see yourself the log IP is the same as the rule IP
2: Not something I'd like to do - I access my server from multiple machines, one of which is a dynamic IP
3: Webmin GUI is currently running on port 10000 - the bot is trying 3~ ports none of which are that port

Ideally I just want to lock a host out after 5 - 10 failed attempts for a day. I know cPanel had better brute force protection. This is just a temporary stopgap till I find something similar

Comment: 2. You could allow a hole range of ip's that you currently use on the specific port , and deny all others (-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT 193.x.x.x and drop all others on the webmin port . It's a good general rule to have the firewall on deny all and allow only the ports that you are using from specific IP ranges - like country / provider specific if you can't give only one IP . . Then he can test all the ports that he wants :) .